# Disable Screen Lock(Power) Button in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-wake-lock

I want that when my application is running the power button (which upon pressing locks the screen & screen goes BLACK), should be disabled. So that the user cannot lock the screen.

I have noticed this thing in Samsung Galaxy S phone's Default Camera App. That's the same reason I am trying to do the same. I have also a Camera related App.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Answer (score 8):

try this one

```
int val=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                                                                SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT);

                    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                                                            SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, -1);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled Screen Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putInt("ScreenTimeout",val);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } catch(Throwable er) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error "+er.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

that will set screen off

to disable key guard in android use

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

and use permition

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

---

to keep screen alive

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Comment: in order to use that need     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

Comment: I am not looking for TIMEOUT. I am talking about Disable POWER BUTTON.

Comment: i noticed that later, i did change my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see that the phone is not locked now but the screen is still going black. How can we avoid this? Anyways I am voting up for your answer. Thanks.

Comment: i added code into below the answer, try that out getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Answer (score 3):

I have reached this using root access.

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
insert into secure (name, value) values ('lockscreen.disabled', 1);
```

or depending on version

```
sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db
insert into locksettings (name, value) values ('lockscreen.disabled', 1);
```

Comment: i am not understand . can you brief to me please.