# Disable the shutdown dialog when the user longpress the power button

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to disallow the user to use the long key press of the power button for security application and I have tried the on long key press method but the dialog still appears is there any way to disable the dialog from appearing?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

            Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

        if(!hasFocus) {
            Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible from the Android API, as mentioned here:

[How to disable power button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036701/how-to-disable-power-button)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is not possible. But even if you could do it, isnt it possible to remove battery which would defeat the whole point.

Comment: Is it possible to over wrote this behavior by trying to use the power button asba camera shutter? Saw this suggestion in another question

Comment: i think only Custom ROM can do this. Since power button is handled in frameworks, the power button event will not reach the app.

Answer (score -4):

Just use the disable() method.

$Button1->Shutdown.disable();

Comment: How would you get the handle of the power button?

Comment: I don't see this documented anywhere where did you find it? Going to try this when I get home