# How to block an app on screen mobile?

Tags: android

good evening. I'm developing a mobile app for Android and need some solution to fix / lock the app on the screen without the possibility of the user leaving the app while using or accessing any other functionality available on the mobile device. Anyone know of a solution? Is this only possible with mdm?

Comment: That's not possible on stock Android, you would need a custom ROM that at least removes the stack button and the notifications drop down menu.

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333464/block-all-way-to-close-a-android-application

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333464/block-all-way-to-close-a-android-application